# UILabel overlap in UICollectionView Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, uilabel, overlap

I needed to create a UICollectionView containing the profiles of users searched in my database.
The UICollectionView must contain a UILabel and a UIImage, the name and image must be taken from PHP. I currently get both, but when I go to do a new search, the old information overlaps the new, creating a confusing effect like this:

[image]

I am developing on xamarin.ios, I am attaching the portion of code that deals with the visual output of the UILabel and UIImage elements.

```
 public void UpdateCell(string elemento)
    {
        img = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("ProfiloImgNotFound"));

        UILabel name = new UILabel { Text = elemento, TextColor = UIColor.SecondaryLabelColor, TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center };
        Console.WriteLine(name.Text);
        name.Font = UIFont.FromName(".AppleSystemUIFont", 20);
        
        var labelHeight = 20;
        var labelWidth = img.Bounds.Width;
        name.Frame = new CGRect(0, img.Bounds.Height + 10, labelWidth, labelHeight);
        AddSubviews(new UIView[] { img, name });
    }
```

Comment: Did you remove the old subview before add the new ImageView and Label ?

Comment: no, I think new label overwrite old label, how I can do it?

Comment: Set the BackgorundColor as white .

Comment: I try with this, ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White; but don't work.

Comment: It not a good design to add multi subviews . You could update the text  of label and image of ImageView .

Comment: I already try with Add(), but is the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223152/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-alessandro-ledda).